# Conditionally override the model Django admin successfully saved message

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am overriding the save method on a Django model. There are some cases where I do not save the model. In these cases, I can't seem to be able to figure out how to conditionally override the "The citation 1111 was added successfully." message that is shown after returning back to the admin list interface (as opposed to the entry form interface).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can override that just by overriding `save` Django's admin interface uses model forms and the messages framework.

I think something like this happens, it's more complicated than this but more or less:

#### models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(...)
    bar = models.CharField(...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.foo == self.bar:  # We only save if foo == bar
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### forms.py (Django admin uses model forms, so this is an example)

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

#### views.py

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'MyModel was saved!.')
```

Now regardless of what form.save() actually did the message is still sent out anyway, we have no way of knowing if you saved or not in your overridden save method and this is probably whats happening in the django admin system.

An alternative would be to create a custom model form for the admin to use for this model and define a custom validation method, so the form doesn't validates unless foo == bar. Or you could override the save method on the form, you'll need to have a look around the django admin code, it probably is possible, just a bit trixy :p